# Even and odd buffers in UIView drawRect?

Tags: iphone, uiview, drawrect

Hello again (I thank you all for your previous invaluable help).

The new issue: I am working up physics simulation but have encountered a problem with a toy version.  All it does is draw a random rectangle on the iPhone/Touch screen each time `NSStimer timer` calls the `tick` method.  I've indexed these calls by `int frameCount`.  What one sees is two sets of images gradually building up: one set for the even frames, another for the odd.  I validated this by drawing `frameCount` to the screen with the even and odd counts in slightly different positions.  Thus one sees the counts blinking back and forth synchronously with the image in the frame.  The abbreviated code is below.  I appreciate any suggestions you might have.  It seems to me that there must be two offscreen buffers.  But I'm in the dark here:-)  And even if this is true, I don't know how to merge them, or copy one to the other.

```
#define MAXFRAMES 1000
```

// Relevant parts of implemenation of FooBar, a subclass of UIView:

```
 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        // Initialization code
        // Start a timer that will call the tick method of this class
        // 30 times per second  -- slowed way down for diagnostics

        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(3.0/1.0)
                    target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        frameCount = 0;
        self.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO;
        NSLog(@"frame initialized");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)tick
{    
    // Tell the view that it needs to re-draw itself
    if (frameCount < MAXFRAMES) {
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
        frameCount++;
    }   
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Draw a random rectangle with CGContextFillRect 
    // after calling CGContextSetRGBFillColor
    // Both called with suitable random parameters  

    // Draw the frameCount for diagnostic purposes

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of buffers that a UIView might use in its drawing layer is unspecified.  If you want to copy drawings, you should draw from and into your own CG drawing context(s), and then use or draw your result into an image that you can use as a view's CALayer contents.